# Recovering folder from Recycle Bin in Windows 7 using command line tools

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I want to move all files in recycle bin folder to original location or desired location using command prompt.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Firstly open your command prompt
2. MS-DOS window, the directory will be C:\Users\ (Your User Name) \ in Windows 7 and C:\Documents and Settings\ (Your User Name) \ in Windows XP
3. cd../.. and press enter .
4. cd $Recycle.Bin in Win7 or cd RECYCLER in WinXP   and press enter.
5. cd and press tab . You'll see that the line is filled with a directory name like this "S-1-5-21-564594560-2944949298-4040108220-1000". Press enter.
6. dir/a to see all the files including hidden files in that directory. The file you want to recover will also be there. But the name of the file may be changed.
7. Here deleted a system file named "BOOTSECT.BAK". Its been renamed as "$I1R8ZP3.BAK"
8. copy (The Name of the File) (The location) 
   For eg., type copy $I1R8ZP3.BAK C:\
9. cd../.. to go to the root directory.
10. dir and enter. You'll see the file you copied from the Recycle Bin directory there
11. ren (The Name of the File) (The Name You Want) 
    For eg., type ren $I1R8ZP3.BAK BOOTSECT.BAK
12. Thats great it! The file is restored. Restart your computer

Comment: Please List your sources

Comment: actually from begining i want give this link but, super user said you cant not write see : http://thetechtrickz.blogspot.com/2011/12/restore-files-from-recycle-bin-through.html
and i also cant sent images like your answer

Comment: Its a reputation thing, you just need more… (up voted to get you started).

Comment: While I cannot comment on previous comments you have gotten I would think that when someone says "do not just write see:…" they are objecting to posts that contain nothing but that statement and link. Since you have quoted the important bits from elsewhere I would say adding the link only helps you.

Comment: @ user139713 you can access it http://www.geekgirls.com/windows_recycle_bin.htm may be this link is important for you

Comment: @Justin : actually from begining i want give this link in my answer but, super user said you cant not write see : http://www.ehow.com/how_5188576_recover-files-recycle-bin-dos.html
and i also cant sent images like your answer
but i just known i can list the source in command. thanks for your command Justin

Comment: thanks so much Justin.. I am sorry because I am earlier join superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer is listed at the following site:

http://thetechtrickz.blogspot.com/2011/12/restore-files-from-recycle-bin-through.html

In short:

**Step 6:** Type cd $Recycle.Bin in Win7 or cd RECYCLER in WinXP and press enter.

**Step 7:** Type cd and press tab. You'll see that the line is filled with a directory name like this "S-1-5-21-564594560-2944949298-4040108220-1000". Press enter.

**Step 8:** Type dir/a to see all the files including hidden files in that directory. The file you want to recover will also be there. But the name of the file may be changed.

**Step 9:** Here I deleted a system file named "BOOTSECT.BAK". Its been renamed as "$I1R8ZP3.BAK"

[image]

**Step 10:** Type copy (The Name of the File) (The location)
For eg., type copy $I1R8ZP3.BAK C:\

**Step 11:** Type cd../.. to go to the root directory.

**Step 12:** Type dir and enter. You'll see the file you copied from the Recycle Bin directory there.

[image]

**Step 13:** Type ren (The Name of the File) (The Name You Want)
For eg., type ren $I1R8ZP3.BAK BOOTSECT.BAK

Note: The above steps and images are taken directly from the blog http://thetechtrickz.blogspot.com/2011/12/restore-files-from-recycle-bin-through.html