# Windows 10: move/copy file by command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I was an idiot and deleted EUBKMON.SYS to waste bin since it was always causing a blue screen. Now Windows 10 doesnt boot.

The file was in the waste bin, now i managed to open command prompt via Advanced Options but neither know the file path to the trash bin nor how i could copy and paste EUBKMON.SYS back to C:\Windows\System32\drivers folder.

I wild be really happy if somebody could help me out.
Perhaps there is also another solution without reinstalling Windows etc. Dont ask for restoring Windows pleas i dont have a backup.

Comment: I think that single copying may not help... I recommend You to boot from some recovery CD/flash and use any offline registry editor to disable all services related to 'EaseUS Todo Backup' setting their Start to 4. **!!! DON'T FORGET TO STORE the initial values of keys You have altered (including full paths to them) !!!** If bad luck try to disable the driver mentioned above by this way too.

Comment: This could help: https://superuser.com/q/435973/376602

Comment: Thank You so much Akina :) you suggestion “This could help” really worked. The trashbin wasnt in the suggested Location mentioned in that thread, instead it was on the root directory. Also when entering the cmd console via Advanced Options of the Bluescreen the Windows drive C: turned to be H: but after all i followed that Thread, found trashbin, the renamed deleted file, copied it back into H:.../drivers, renamed it back to EUBKMON.SYS. And after rebooting Windows loaded up, surprisingly as if nothing happened.